# How to stream music to an Icecast server using C#?

Tags: c#, streaming, icecast, bass.dll

I'm trying to find a way to send music to an IceCast server and retrieve the URL related to it. I downloaded BASS.NET API, but I don't understand ANYTHING ! Did someone already used it, or have a not so complicated alternative for me ??? I need to do that in 3 days, so pleeeeeease help me !

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating audio may be too difficult for unexperienced developers. I don't think 3 days will be enough.

I suggest you to read Bass documentation as Bass.net is just a wrapper.

Don't hesitate to ask questions in the Bass forum.